# Floating label on bottom works but top doesn't

Tags: html, forms, css, label

So I made a floating label for forms but the problem is that when I put the labels on top it doesn't appear, but if it's at the bottom its appears. I don't know where's the problem exactly.

Here is my code, I made two forms to show you the difference between the two labels. 
Please check it and identify my problem :) Thank you!

```css
.forms {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
}
.field-container {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.field {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  margin: -5px 0;
}
.field input {
  color: blue;
}
.field:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #2580cd;
}
.floating-label {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.field:valid + .floating-label {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: -12px;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
.field:focus + .floating-label {
  color: #2580cd;
}
.field:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2580cd;
}
/* THE OTHER ONE */

.field-container2 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.field2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  margin: -5px 0;
}
.field2:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #2580cd;
}
.floating-label2 {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.field2:valid + .floating-label2 {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
.field2:focus + .floating-label2 {
  color: #2580cd;
}
.field2:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2580cd;
}
```

```html
<div class="forms">
  <form class="field-container">
    <input type="text" class="field" required placeholder="Label 1" />
    <label class="floating-label">Label 1</label>
  </form>

  <form class="field-container2">
    <label class="floating-label2">Label 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="field2" required placeholder="Label 2" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` CSS selector only works on adjacent elements, since your selector is `.field + .label`, and your the `label` in `field-container2` precedes the `input`, it won't be selected under that CSS rule.

Comment: I changed the code the way you said it but still it doesn't change a thing. It doesn't appear.

Comment: @user2522053 I think you misread my answer – I'm saying that the `+` selector you're using won't work when the label is above the input, which is why you're having that problem.

Comment: @user2522053 without JavaScript, you won't be able to accomplish what you want without having the label below the input. Most CSS frameworks currently have the label at the bottom so that they can use `input:focus + label` and then just transform the label as they see fit